# Working with empty lists

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, slice

Okay so I am trying to create an empty list, then add integers to the list to then pick out the highest,lowest and 5 middle numbers( in descending order using a slice) and put them on display... seems simple enough....

```
def main():
    nums = []
    for i in range(20,80,9):
        nums.append(i)
        print(*nums,sep=' ')
        print('The highest number is',max(nums))
        print('The lowest number is',min(nums))
        print('The middle 5 sorted high to low:')
        nums.sort()
        nums.reverse()
        print (*nums[1:6])
main()
```

Okay so i edited it using your suggestions and the program works fine..... I just cant wrap my head around that damned while loop.... Can anyone see how I could integrate that?

Comment: You probably want to tag this with the language you are working in.

Comment: Also, what's the while loop doing?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using python and added the tag, and I HAVE to have a while loop in here

Comment: @lebler who told you `list.append(i)` returns a `boolean` value?

Comment: i've been fumbling through a book which is my only resource in the class no lectures or anything, unfortunately this makes me just regurgitate what is in the book to the best of my ability which until now has worked fine haha.

Comment: @lebler why do you need to have `while` loop there?

Comment: its a requirement of the assignment i'm trying to complete

Comment: The python documentation is known for its readability and understandability. You should really refer to the docs for information; they'll give you everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `while nums.append(i):`. list.append returns None, and None does not evaluate to true. So your print statements will never be executed.
2. `nums.reverse[2:6]` reverse is a method and reverses the list in place. It does not return anything. So this part will throw a `TypeError`. You want to instead call `nums.reverse()`
3. The reverse method does not sort. You need `nums.sort()`
4. `nums[2:6]` will get you the elements from index 2 to 6 (exclusive). So this will only get you 4 elements. Additionally, your list has 9 elements (7 if you exclude the min and max). The middle 5 elements would not be between index 2 and 6.

Python has a `help()` function, use it if you need to know what functions/methods return.

Comment: In fact just type `help()` and type `list` and it will give you everything on the list data type.

Comment: so i should just go back to square one and start over?

Comment: @lebler You have the right idea in getting the maximum and minimum number. But you need to move the print statement outside of the loop, then make the appropriate changes so you can correctly get the middle 5 numbers in sorted order. However, I can't see any need for a while loop, so I'm not sure why your assignment requires it.

Comment: I could put the assignment just so you guys can see whats being asked maybe I am not reading it correctly, i thought the while loop wasn't necessary either

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
nums = []
for i in range(20,80,7):
    nums.append(i)
    mx = max(nums)
    mn = min(nums)

nums.remove(mx)
nums.remove(mn)
mx2 = max(nums)
mn2 = min(nums)
nums.remove(mx2)
nums.remove(mn2)
nums.sort()
nums.reverse()
print nums
```

The output is the 5 middle numbers in descending order:

`[62, 55, 48, 41, 34]`

and the better, shorter way to do it is this:

```
def main():
    nums = []
    for i in range(20,80,7):
        nums.append(i)
        mx = max(nums)
        mn = min(nums)
    print "The highest number is %s " % mx
    print "The lowest number is %s " % mn
    while len(nums) != 5:
        nums.remove(max(nums))
        nums.remove(min(nums))
    nums.sort()
    nums.reverse()
    print "The middle 5 sorted high to low is %s:" % nums
main()
```

The output is:

`The highest number is 76 
The lowest number is 20 
The middle 5 sorted high to low is [62, 55, 48, 41, 34]`

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your code to use a while loop like so.

```
def main():
    nums = []
    i = 20
    while i < 80:
        nums.append(i)
        print(*nums,sep=' ')
        i += 9

    print('The highest number is',max(nums))
    print('The lowest number is',min(nums))
    print('The middle 5 sorted high to low:')
    # removed on the basis that they are already sorted
    #nums.sort()
    nums.reverse()
    print (*nums[1:6])
main()
```

It's just a lot nicer using `range` as you don't need to the `i` variable outside the scope of the loop.